# yii CFormModel dynamic properties

Tags: php, yii

i got such form

```
    class CC extends CFormModel
{
    public $static_field;
    public $fields;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('static_field, testF', 'required')
        );
    }



    public function getForm()
    {
        return new CForm(array(
            'showErrorSummary'=>true,
            'elements'=>array(
                'static_field'=>array(),
                'testF'=>array(),
            ),
            'buttons'=>array(
                'submit'=>array(
                    'type'=>'submit',
                    'label'=>'Next'
                )
            )
        ), $this);
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'static_field' => 'static_field'
        );
    }


    public function  __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->fields[$name]))
            return $this->fields[$name];
        else
            return '';
    }

    public function  __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->fields[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

i want to add dynamical field `testF`

i try to use `__get\__set` and array for values, but nothing work. any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't look like MVC to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by dynamic you mean not required, you can add it as a property just as you have done with static_field.  All attributes, or fields, are encapsulated member data of your FormModel class.  So, if you wanted to add your dynamic_field attribute, you could add it in this manner:

```
class CC extends CFormModel
{
    public $static_field;
    public $dynamic_field;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('static_field','required'),
            array('dynamic_field','safe'),
        );
    }
}
```

Also, you're not exactly following the dominant usage pattern for this type of class.  If I were you, I would suggest creating some CRUD through gii and examining the usage patterns for models and forms.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but you can't dynamically redefine the structure of a class at runtime in php, like you can in some other languages (e.g. Ruby).  You can mock the functionality with magic methods, but unless you're more specific about what you want to do with the properties, I can't be much help to you.  You won't be able to enforce validation on properties that aren't included in the rules read-only attribute, however.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do now, but I'm not sure why.  Why would a dynamic attribute have the required rule?  Any attributes that may or may not be assigned when validated should just be passed to a 'safe' validator.

Comment: i take properties from database fo i can't define them at code

Comment: Yes you can.  You pass those attributes which may be null at runtime to a 'safe' validator.  Then, you set the attributes from the model in this manner, $CC->setAttributes($myModel->getAttributes());